# Insert 2 rows 5 rows before end

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have a macro, on command, find the last used cell in Column A and then insert 2 rows before the 5 rows preceding that last cell.

I have found the following code on stackoverflow for finding the last used cell, but have not been able to use this to add 2 rows.

```
Dim LastRow As Long
' Find the last row in column "C" (pass in whatever column you want, obviously)
LastRow = Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
rw = LastRow - 5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(Trim(rw) + ":" + Trim(rw + 1)).Insert
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Just to verify, will this add one or two rows?

Comment: @user989937: The above will insert two rows. @gordon613: You can remove the `TRIM` and change "+" to "&" for concatenation ` ActiveSheet.Rows(rw & ":" & (rw + 1)).Insert`

Comment: @user989937: One imp advice. You might want to check and ensure that the lastrow is greater than 5 else your code will give you an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. One more question please:  Say I wanted to insert "Deffered Expenses" in the first of the new cells in column, A, how would I go about doing that?